# Bash script to send warning about filessystem percentage usage to email

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, filesystems

I'm writing a bash script that copy the details of files system information in a file then replace the spaces with `;` in a different file "fs_sizes1" so that I have different fields, and then send that file to my mail like below

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#script to send fs_sizes

df -h > fs_sizes

awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=";" fs_sizes >fs_sizes1

size=$(df -kh | awk '$6 == "/var" {print $5}')

size=${size%"%"}

if (( size > 50 )); then

    echo "/var is more than 50 % full" >>fs_sizes1

elif  (( size > 70 )); then

    echo "/var is more than 70 % full" >>fs_sizes1
fi

if [ $? -eq 0 ]

then 
    echo "operation succesful" && mail -s "size of Fs of server X" example@mail.com < fs_sizes1

       exit 0
else

       echo "operation fail"

       exit
```

For now the information of `Fs` is properly copied into my file and sended to my email, but my current problem is that my `if` statment doesn't show me the filesystem usage that are more than 50 % and 70% and there is no error message when I execute the script.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Welcome, besides other problems, if `(( size > 50 ))` then is already greater than 70.

Comment: 1) is proper shebanh (e.g. `#!` ) missing or is it a copy/paste typo ? 2) running script as `bash -x script.sh` will produce debug information (value of `size` for instance)

Comment: i want to send diffrent message if there is at least one fs >50 or >70.

Comment: and yes @Archemar shebanh is a typo and the debug doesnt help me

Comment: @dantex if it's >50 it will never check if it's >70.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity yes you are right thank you i will delete one statement, but do you have an idea why the script doesn't work? i forgat to mention that the field of my percentage is 5